# order results by score of two combined sets of data (Solr)

Tags: solr

I have docs with following structure:

```
{
    id: 1
    type: 1 
    prop1: "any value"
    prop2: "any value"
    ...
    ...
}
```

`type` can be `1 or 2`

Now I would like to create a query which returns all of type 1 and limited (LIMIT = 100) results of type 2  with filtering props and ordering by score.

My try so far is as follow, which isn't correct, resp. sorting by score isn't correct:

I combine two queries:

- prepare a first query for using in the mainquery : `type:2 AND commonfilters, size=LIMIT, sort by score, ID` -> returns a list of id's
- main query : `(type:1 AND commonfilters) OR (id:[ids from first query]), sort by score, ID`

The order isn't correct (sort by score), because it was sorted for two different independent sets of data and not sorted over all id's in combination.

What I need is something like the following SQL Query:

```
select * from data where commonfilters order by score, id MINUS (select * from data where rowcount > LIMIT)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve correct ordering for this case?

Comment: Use `fq=type:1 OR id:([ids from first query])` and the commonfilters as your main query; that way the only thing affecting the score is `commonfilters` and not the other filters.

Comment: No thats not working. All the id's from the OR clause will get a higher score then it would be fetched with the simple commonfilter. (without building two sets). Example : (type:1 OR id:100) AND commonfilter -> id 100 gets unexpected higher score, what it would not have if I would just filter with commonfilters.

Comment: `fq` doesn't affect score, which is why you add the filtering there - and use the common filters in `q` which _does_ affect score. This is why I suggest using the part about which documents to include (filtering) in the filter query (`fq`), and the actual query (that affects score) in the query part (`q`).